# How to validate date and time format with time zone?

Tags: java, regex, datetime

I need to make sure that my date is written using one of the following formats:
**06-01-2023 11:59 PM ET** or **06/01/2023 11:59 PM ET**

I tried to use the following regex, but it didn't work out:

```
^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})Z$
```

Can somebody please help me with regex and let me know how can I achieve the desired format for my date and time?

Comment: Something like this? `^\d\d([-/])\d\d\1\d{4} \d\d:\d\d [AP]M ET$` https://regex101.com/r/nZC9PB/1

Comment: How is this regex used? Does _...is written using..._ really referring to parsing?

Comment: You should really use `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` instead of regex.

Comment: I would suggest you read up on regex first. The sample regex you've given matches a date format of `2023-06-01T11:59:00Z` which really doesn't bear any resemblance to the format you're trying to match.

Comment: Is that 06 January or June 01 or one of each?

Comment: Don’t use 11:59 PM to represent the end of the day. Use 00:00 AM on the following day. That is when the day ends.

Answer (score 2):

## *java.time*

Rather than use [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), you can use *java.time* classes.

Specify a `DateTimeFormatter` object for each of your expected inputs. Attempt to parse the input with each of these. If `DateTimeParseException` is thrown, you know the input does not match that formatter — move on to the next formatter. If no exception, then you have a match. If all of the formatters throw the exception, then you have an unexpected invalid input.

In most situations, you should *never* [swallow an exception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_hiding). But here is an exception to the rule; here it makes sense. We expect at least 2 of our 3 formatters will fail to parse, and possibly all three.

Your second case is peculiar in that it combines a time-of-day with a pseudo time zone, `ET`. Java does include a class [`OffsetTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetTime.html) for a time combined with an offset-from-UTC. But (a) that class makes no sense logically; I presume that class was included merely for compatibility with the same illogical data type defined in the [SQL standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL). And, (b) your input uses a pseudo [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone), not an [offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset). To resolve this conundrum, I use the `LocalTime` class which represents solely a time-of-day, no date, no time zone, no offset.

```java
package work.basil.example.time;

import java.time.format.*;
import java.time.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class App5
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        App5 app = new App5();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        List < String > inputs =
                List.of(
                        "06-01-2023" ,
                        "11:59 PM ET" ,
                        "06/01/2023 11:59 PM ET" ,
                        "bogus"
                );
        for ( String input : inputs )
        {
            // LocalDate
            try
            {
                LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( input , DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MM-uuuu" ) );
                System.out.println( "Found a match for LocalDate: " + localDate );
                continue;
            }
            catch ( DateTimeParseException e )
            {
                // Ignore here. Try other formatters.
            }

            // LocalTime
            try
            {
                LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse( input , DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "hh:mm a v" ).withLocale( Locale.US ) );
                System.out.println( "Found a match for OffsetTime: " + localTime );
                continue;
            }
            catch ( DateTimeParseException e )
            {
                // Ignore here. Try other formatters.
            }

            // ZonedDateTime
            try
            {
                ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse( input , DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd/uuuu hh:mm a v" ).withLocale( Locale.US ) );
                System.out.println( "Found a match for ZonedDateTime: " + zdt );
                continue;
            }
            catch ( DateTimeParseException e )
            {
                // Ignore here. Try other formatters.
            }

            // Reaching this point means the input in unexpected, invalid. 
            System.out.println( "ERROR - Input is invalid: " + input );
        }
    }
}
```

When run:

```
Found a match for LocalDate: 2023-01-06
Found a match for OffsetTime: 23:59
Found a match for ZonedDateTime: 2023-06-01T23:59-04:00[America/New_York]
ERROR - Input is invalid: bogus
```

### ISO 8601

FYI, such custom localized formats are a terrible way to communicate date-time values textually. Educate the publisher of your data about the virtues of using standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats for data exchange and data storage.